# Unable to locate elements inside another element using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to **scrape** a website with a structure like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p>
        <a href="href1">Text1</a>
        <a href="href2">Text2</a>
        <a href="href3">Text3</a>
        .   .    .
        .   .    .
    </p>
    <p> .  .  . </p>
    # More <p> elements with <a> as childrens
    </td>
    <td> .  .  . </td
    # More <td> elements
    </tr>
    <tr> .  .  . </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

I want to get these `<a>` elements (text and href). The code that I have is:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table")
elems = elem.find_elements_by_xpath("./p/a")
print(len(elems))
for i in elems:
    print(i.text)
    time.sleep(4)
```

The length of elems prints `0` so basically the elements are not found. I have tried `./a` alone also instead of `./p/a` but same result. I am new to selenium so please help.

Comment: I don't use xpath. I use css selector. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table p > a')`

Answer (score 0):

try to use xpath

for getting all a tag elements

```
//table//tbody//child::p[1]//a
```

for getting specific a tag element

```
//table//tbody//child::p[1]//a[1]
//table//tbody//child::p[1]//a[2]
//table//tbody//child::p[1]//a[3]
```

Comment: So if I do this `//table//tbody//child::p//a` This will get me all a tags inside all p tags that are children of tbody right?

Comment: No this won't provide you all p tag elements, as we have to narrow it down to tag a. If you want to get all p tag elements you need to use below given xpath 
 //table//tbody//child::p

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the texts by using the code:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'href')]")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Comment: There might be some other a tags in the page that I do not want. I just wrote the part that I wanted to extract in the question. But there are some other a tags in header and footer of the page that I do not want.

Comment: @A.Hamza  Ok, then you can use the xpath: `//table//p//a[contains(@href,'href')]`, this would only return the values which you want